# Do I need UFW in a Linux VM in Azure?

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, ufw

Access to Azure VMs are controlled by the "Network Security Group" (NSG) settings. I am in the process of setting up a Linux VM with a public IP on Azure and would like to know whether the NSG settings are sufficient to protect my VM, or do I need to enable UFW in addition?

To me it seems that having both the NSG and UFW are like "wearing belt and suspenders". However, I would like to know the opinion of people more experienced like me before I give up the belt (or the suspenders :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to have defense in depth. The belt-and-suspenders combo is good if there's a chance somebody will misconfigure one or the other over the lifetime of the server - and you know there is.

Of course it adds the requirement that the people working on deployment scripts are aware of the multiple layers that need to be configured.

Comment: Thank you, I like the "defense in depth" argument. Since I plan to keep only a few ports open anyway, it's not that much work to configure them both in the NSG and in the firewall app of the VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to implement something like `fail2ban` to protect from malicious brute force attacks, you'll need a firewall (iptables, ufw or other) on the VM guest. `fail2ban` works by monitoring the logs of your public services and modifying local VM firewall rules to block bad actors.